# Mount client files with an SSH connection from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ssh

I am currently using Putty to connect from a Windows 7 computer to a Linux server with SSH. The target Linux server is not in the same network; the connection goes through the internet.

I want to somehow *mount* the files of my Windows User Profile folder (C:\Users\MyAccount) read- and writable from the Linux server (not only access single files), so that I can use a tool like tar or rsync on them.

I do **not** have administrative permissions on the Windows computer, but am root on the Linux server, which can be only accessed with its default SSH port 22.

What can I do to achieve this? I thought about tunneling the local SMB port to the remote server, and using cifs-vfs on that connection. Is there a better / an easier way?

Comment: Grsync on windows supports ssh, so you could achieve that without mounting at least

Comment: @Paul thank you, but I really do need to mount the files, as I want (amongst others) to use the connection to cross-compile applications and diff the content against only remotely accessible locations